# Problemas com Width

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, estou com um problema em meu projeto,
no topo do meu site quero uma imagem e um bloco azul,
como representado abaixo,
[image: topo]

Ambos estão dentro de uma div#topo com height: 10% e width: 100%;
A imagem tem um height: 100%; e um width: auto; para ficar sempre quadrada e proporcional ao tamanho da tela.

No div#bloco_azul eu uso position: absolute e width: 89%, mas se tela for de tamanhos diferentes ele fica maior ou menor e aparece barra de rolagem, acaba ficando assim : 
[image: topo]

ou assim :
[topo http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/56ee/iqmqr2nij89eu18zg.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/56ee/iqmqr2nij89eu18zg.jpg)

Aqui está o código :
**HTML**

```
<div id="topo">
    <img id="logo" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/ab86/gyn33csao1jj3jazg.jpg"/>
    <div id="bloco_azul"><img id="logo2" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/4b1a/1004wqw2lh36au6zg.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

topo {
    height: 21%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

img#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0,1);
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

div#bloco_azul {
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #4795cf;
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 89%;                       /* Aqui fica o width do bloco azul */
    height: 10%;
}

img#logo2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Oque devo fazer ? Desde já, Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz o seguinte, ver se lhe atende:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vqjmnodq/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="imagem"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#imagem {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
    z-index: 3;
}

#header {
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    height: 8.9%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#content {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 91.1%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var imagem = $("#imagem");
$(window).resize(function() {
    imagem.innerWidth(imagem.innerHeight());
});
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito Obrigado !!! Que Deus te Abençoe muito!!!

Comment: @DanilloEder, evite fazer comentarios com +1, funcionou, etc. em vez disto, apenas faça um upvote em forma de agradecimento.

Comment: @DanilloEder você deve marcar esta resposta como correta, assim outros membros saberão que isto solucionou seu problema!